# Chrome Extension: How to escape an ampersand used with chrome.contextMenus.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Chrome is ignoring ampersands in context menu titles. For example, the following expression creates a menu with the title `this  that` instead of `this & that`.

```js
await chrome.contextMenus.create({id: '123', contexts: ['all'], type: 'normal', title: 'this & that'})
```

I've tried some common escapes, such as `\&`, `&amp;` and `\u0026`.

Both Chrome and Firefox have this issue, so I'm optimistic that this is not a bug and that there is a way to make this work...

Comment: According to the linked question, use `&&`